# Can't install Kmymoney in 16.04

Tags: kde, kmymoney

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 kmymoney was removed, now cannot be re-installed.

I've tried from Ubuntu software centre and terminal with `sudo apt-get install` but I get this. How do I proceed to
install? I need to access my accounts.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kmymoney : Depends: kde-runtime (> 4:4.10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libkabc4 (>= 4:4.4.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libkfile4 (>= 4:4.4.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libkhtml5 (>= 4:4.4.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libkio5 (>= 4:4.4.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
howard@coaching:~$
```

Comment: The message "you have held broken package" makes me think that you should try this "apt-mark showhold" to list all the available held packages, and then remove them with "sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>". After, you may want to try using aptitude which is better than apt-get to solve problems.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kmymoney
```

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>  to open terminal

Answer (score -1):

After running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kmymoney
```

The app will be installed, but will not appear on the launcher.
click on "search your computer" and in the search window click the "A" at the bottom:

1. You will see a display of installed apps - click on "see more results".
2. You will then see the installed `kmymoney`. Click it and the app will open.
3. The icon will now appear on the launcher. To keep it there, right click it and choose "lock to launcher".

Job done!